# Why is this failing to compile?

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I have an requirement to execute an expression which contains math and conditional statements and a switch statement. What I've tried is this:

```
20 + 10 + (if (20 > 10){ return 0.2; } else { return 0.1; }) //+ switch case
```

Now the compiler throws compilation errors for this expression. Why, and how can I fix it so it does work?

Comment: `switch` is a type of *statement* - not an *expression* which can be used as part of another expression. Personally, I'm pleased about that - it would be horrible to read otherwise, I suspect. You can always extract the switch/case into a method though. The if/else part can be done with a conditional expression.

Comment: You should use correct switch case syntax; also you have missed return 0.1 in the else brackets. Rgds,

Comment: What are you trying to do here? It looks really quite confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the ['?' operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for the inline 'if/else'.

As for the inline switch statement, I would suggest using a static `Dictionary` instead;

So your line

```
20 + 10 +(if(20>10){ return 0.2} else{ 0.1 }) + switch case
```

Becomes

```
20 + 10 + (20 > 10 ? 0.2 : 0.1) + _switchDictionary[switchKey]
```

Answer (score 1):

The why: `if .. else ..` is a statement, not an expression.

The way to do it: Use the `?` operator:

```
20+10+(20>10)?0.2:0.1+(case_condtion_1)?case_value_1:((case_condtion_2)?case_value_2:(...))
```

Comment: Our client does not wish to use a ternary operator.

Comment: Well, `if ... else ...` is a ternary operation. The difference is syntax only.

Comment: @user984369 See my confusing answer if you don't like to use ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use `if` you can modify your expression like this:

```
20 + 10 + ((Func<double>) (() => { if (20 > 10){ return 0.2; } else { return 0.1; }}))();
```

But, it will really confusing. Better you use `?` operator as @Murkaeus said.